# Applescript - submitting a password that contains an ampersand

Tags: applescript

I have been attempting to create an Applescript that will enable a High Sierra secure token on an account (via Jamf's Self Service).  It worked fine until an attempt was made for someone whose password contained an ampersand character within the password.  Is there a specific syntax needed when using 'run shell script' within an applescript in order to avoid problems with ampersands contained within a variable?  Thanks for any help with this one.

This is the applescript:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set the_folder to (path to users folder)
tell application "Finder"
set foldernames to name of every folder of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list foldernames with prompt "Select user to receive secure token"
display dialog "Password for " & theChosenOne default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with hidden answer
set thePassword to text returned of the result
do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenOn " & theChosenOne & " -password " & thePassword
set theVerification to do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenStatus " & theChosenOne & " 2>&1 | awk -F']' '{print $2}'"
display dialog theVerification
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to escape an ampersand in AppleScript, you need to wrap the string (or the variable) with `quoted form`.

In your case:

```
set thePassword to quoted form of text returned of the result
```